# Receiving an email through python?

Tags: python, email

I want to be able to receive an email and get an acknowledgement from python by opening my emails.
I would do this by:

```
webbrowser.open("www.mail.google.com")
```

The problem is getting python to understand that an email has been received. I can send emails via the smtp and thought it may involve that any help into being able to do that would be extremly helpful (if its even possible).

Comment: you may want to take a look at the mailgun API.

Comment: Writing a python script that understands Gmail's web interface would be an extremely complicated task and the solution would be subject to breaking any time because the web page was never designed to provide a stable machine-friendly API.  Instead, you should connect to your mail server via IMAP.

Answer (score 2):

Don't scrape gmail, use the API: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/gmail/v1